# Can fabric-node-sdk 1.4 be used with a Fabric 1.2 network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I use fabric-node-sdk 1.4 to make an API server with Fabric 1.4.4 on local It works normally. But when using with service blockchain on AWS, get error:

`error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs:.......`

So I'm not sure because on AWS is fabric version 1.2 or not.
(or is there a way to test ping URL:grpcs:?)

Comment: I doubt hyperledger fabric have tested to see if it will work. I thought I have heard of others using 1.4 with older versions of fabric. Have you tried a 1.2 sdk ? if it has the same problem then at least you know it's not initially because you are using a 1.4 sdk.

Comment: Yes, I have tried a 1.2 sdk and it has the same problem. 
I will try to check the connection profile again. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, I fix the connection profile. I can conclude that fabric-node-sdk 1.4 can be used with fabric 1.2.